# How kafka high /low level consumer API fetch the messages from the broker?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

As I know the kafka consumer only can use the API poll() to pull the messages from the broker, however we know we also can use the kafka high /low level consumer API fetch the messages from the broker, so what's the relationship between kafka high /low level consumer API  and API poll() ? The high /low level consumer API invoke the poll() inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High/Low level consumers are so-called old consumers which are implemented by Scala. The consumers with poll APIs are new consumers, written totally by Java.

Old consumers will be soon deprecated and new consumers are recommended now.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification,xiexie:-)

Comment: @Jason bukeqi~~

Comment: BTW, for the old high  level consumers like below, how it fetch the messages from broker,  doesn't  it use the poll() to fetch the message? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example

Comment: It's hard to explain the whole things in several sentences. Simply put, both consumers honor a manner where clients send FETCH requests to brokers and brokers respond those requests. However, the old consumers employ multiple threads to do these.